# Recursive 'require' for feature 'auto-package-update'

Tags: use-package

I'm trying to use [auto-package-update](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el) to do what it says on the tin. As per the instructions at [use-package documentation](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) I'm using...

```
(use-package auto-package-update
   :ensure t
   :config
   (setq auto-package-update-delete-old-versions t
         auto-package-update-interval 2
         auto-package-update-hide-results t))
   (auto-package-update-maybe))
```

But when I evaluate it I get a recursive require, debugging shows.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Recursive ‘require’ for feature ‘auto-package-upda...")
  require(auto-package-update nil nil)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-796305> nil "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 477
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)
  require(auto-package-update nil nil)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-929330> nil "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 477
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)
  require(auto-package-update nil nil)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-688129> nil "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 477
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)
  require(auto-package-update nil nil)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 477
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." "/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-upd..." nil t)
  require(auto-package-update nil nil)
  eval-region(284 477)  ; Reading at buffer position 284
  funcall-interactively(eval-region 284 477)
  call-interactively(eval-region nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-region)
```

Not sure where I've gone wrong?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what file did you put your call to `use-package` in? Did you modify `auto-package-update.el` at all? Is `auto-package-update.el` bytecompiled (there will be a `.elc` file if it is)?

Comment: The above snippet of code is in `~/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-update.el` which is loaded from `~/.config/emacs/init.el` with `(load "~/.config/emacs/settings/auto-package-update.el")`. Not touched any of the files in `auto-package-update.el` and it is byte compiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(require 'foo)` searches each directory named in `load-path` for a file named `foo.elc` or `foo.el`, and loads it. Likewise, calling `(use-package foo :ensure t)` is the same as calling `(require 'foo)`, and calling any function defined in the foo package will transparently autoload foo by calling `(require 'foo)` for you.

From your comments, I gather that you have placed the `use-package` form you quoted in a file named `auto-package-update.el`. That file is placed in the “/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/” directory, which is in your `load-path`. When it is loaded, it calls `(require 'auto-package-update)`. `require` looks through the `load-path` until it finds the “/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/” directory, where there is a file named “auto-package-update.elc”, which matches the package name that it is looking for. It loads it as instructed.

You can fix this by removing “/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/” from your `load-path`, by giving the file a different name, or just by moving the `use-package` form directly into your init file, which is where most people would place it.

Comment: Thanks, spot on I had `/home/user/.config/emacs/settings/`in my `load-path` removing it and moving the code the loads `auto-package-update` solves the problem. Thank you very much for your explanation and time @db48x

Comment: You’re welcome.